What would the kinematic equations of motion for a ball rolling down a hill with equation $f(x)$? (Let $x$ be the function of the hill.)
I can only find equations about balls going down inclined planes. I would like to see the motion eq's for a ball rolling up and down a curvy hill. especially the velocity and acceleration.
